# notice:indefined index although still put isset

Tags: php, mysql

I'll try put isset but still give me a notice, can you guys help me..like i said before i'm still learning php, i can make the notice disappeared by typing 
            error _reporting (E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); but i still wanna fix it...

```
        Notice: Undefined index: IdUser in C:\wamp\www\contract\content\maintanace\add_newUser.php on line 9
        Notice: Undefined index: Categori in C:\wamp\www\contract\content\maintanace\add_newUser.php on line 10


       $IdUser= isset($_POST['IdUser']);
       $Categori= isset($_POST['Categori']); 

       $IdUser= $_SESSION['IdUser'];
       $Categori= $_SESSION['Categori'];


       $IdUser= (isset($_SESSION['IdUser'])) ? $_SESSION['IdUser'] : false;
       $Categori= (isset($_SESSION['Categori'])) ? $_SESSION['Categori'] : false;

       if($IdUser!='' && $Categori= '1')

            {
                    $apply = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE IdUser=    '".$IdUser."' AND Categori='".$Categori."'");
                    $result = mysql_fetch_array($apply);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

isset returns a true or false value, therefore

```
$IdUser= isset($_POST['IdUser']);
```

Sets $IdUser as either true, or false. This is not what you are trying to accomplish.

Perhaps try something like this? Although I am still not completely sure what you are asking.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['IdUser'])){
//Register SESSION variables.
}
```

Comment: so i put the if loop and inside that i put $IdUser= isset($_POST['IdUser']); , am i right?

Comment: @NixshamBMohamad i dont get the loop part

Comment: @ianace i try this if (isset($IdPengguna)){
    $_SESSION['IdPengguna'] = $IdPengguna;
}
if (isset($Kategori)){
    $_SESSION['Kategori'] =  $Kategori;
}

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the isset on the index of session.

You could try something like this:

```
$IdUser= (isset($_SESSION['IdUser'])) ? $_SESSION['IdUser'] : false;
$Categori= (isset($_SESSION['Categori'])) ? $_SESSION['Categori'] : false;
```

Comment: how to check it..please explain to me

Comment: ooo..i see..now i little bit understand about, and 1 more brendan how about the loop for if?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way or you can do it with a ternary statement

```
 if(isset($_POST['IdUser']) || isset($_POST['Categori']))
        {
        $IdUser = $_POST['IdUser'];
        $Categori= $_POST['Categori']; 
        }
        elseif(isset($_SESSION['IdUser']) || isset($_SESSION['Categori']))
            {
                $IdUser = $_SESSION['IdUser'];
                $Categori= $_SESSION['Categori'];
            }
            else
                {
                    $IdUser = "";
                    $Categori= "";
                }
```

Comment: it work thanks but may i ask u for my note about the loop that you do?

Comment: don't understand what you are asking about loop. But you should not use mysql as it is depreciated. check into Mysqli or PDO